# If $b^*\cdot a=1$, then $\|a.b^*\|=?$

Tags: vectors, normed-spaces

Let $a$ and $b$ two column-vectors $\in C^n$. If we know that the inner product $b^* \cdot a=1$,
(where $b^*$ is conjugate transpose of $b$), what follows for the norm of the matrix $P=a \cdot b^*$
$$
\|P\|_2=?
$$ 
is it equal to $1$?

Comment: Hint: Consider $b=e_1$, $a=e_1 + \alpha e_2$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray}
 \|P\|_2 &=& \sup_\limits{\|z\|=1}\|Pz\|_2\\
&=& \sup_\limits{\|z\|=1} \sqrt{z^*P^*Pz}\\
&=& \sup_\limits{\|z\|=1} \sqrt{z^*ba^*ab^*z}\\
&=&  \|a\|_2\sup_\limits{\|z\|=1}\sqrt{z^*bb^*z}\\
&=& \|a\|_2\|b\|_2\\
&\ge& \vert b^*a\vert = 1
\end{eqnarray}
by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.  By making $\ a\ $ and $\ b\ $ very nearly orthogonal, you can make the product $\ \|a\|_2\|b\|_2\ $ arbitrarily large while still keeping the inner product $\ b^*a=1\ $, so I don't think there's much more you can say about the size of $\ \|P\|_2\ $.

Comment: Thank you very mach for the answers.